# Can a pointer size be 4.75 Bytes

Tags: c

Consider a system with total memory available is 2^(38) bytes. A user write a C program on this system that uses the entire addressing space. What is the size of a pointer (in bytes) defined in this C program.

Comment: And what architecture is this system running on?

Comment: That is not knowable from the memory availability alone. And SO is not a homework-doing service (no matter how poorly written said homework is).

Comment: @underscore_d maybe the question should be "What is the minimum size of a pointer...?"

Comment: The pointer will be 4 or 8 bytes. Which one do you think will be needed to address 2^38 locations?

Comment: Are we to infer that the title is the OP's guess as to the answer to the copy-pasted question, and they're asking for validation? Either way, it can't be answered.

Comment: The program could use 32-bit pointers if the system has a paging mechanism.

Comment: The question was wrongly closed; it is not too broad and can be answered no regarding 4.75-byte pointers and answer with information about the rules of bytes, objects, and pointers in C.

Comment: I presume you obtained `4.75` from a calculation like `38 / 8`

Comment: The question can be answered generally (possibly with a clarification question comment in preparation), with a code fragment which will answer it specifically and with a little detour to discuss the most probable misconceptions OP seems to have (little challenge in tact and diplomacy there...).

Comment: [African or European?](https://youtu.be/_7iXw9zZrLo?t=163)

Answer (score 6):

In C, a *byte* is a fundamental unit. The number of bits in a byte is defined by each individual C implementation. (Eight bits is very common these days but is not mandatory. It is the minimum.)

Per C 2018 6.2.6.1 2, except for bit-fields, each object is composed of a one or more bytes. So a pointer must be a whole number of bytes in its C implementation, although it may be that some bits in the pointer are not used.

The number of bytes a pointer uses is ultimately determined by the C implementation, not by the computer or system its programs run on. By and large, C is intended to be configured to fit a system “naturally,” so pointers and other types tend to match what a machine is designed for. However, C implementations sometimes serve special purposes, such as supporting old source code or making only a subset of memory available in order to conserve resources. For example, on a machine with a 64-bit address space, we could choose to use a 32-bit C implementation because the amount of space consumed by 64-bit pointers is a significant cost for execution of certain programs.

Thus, on a system with 2<sup>38</sup> bytes of memory, 38 bits would be necessary to to address each byte. This leads to several possibilities, including:

- The system has eight-bit bytes, and the C implementation uses five-byte (40-bit) pointers, in which 38 bits represent an address and the other two could be wasted or could be used for some error detection or other features.
- The system has eight-bit bytes, and there is some benefit to alignment, so the C implementation uses eight-byte pointers.
- The system has, hypothetically, 19-bit bytes, and the C implementation uses two of them for a pointer.
- The system has eight-bit bytes, and the C implementation uses four-byte pointers. Only 2<sup>32</sup> bytes are available in the address space of each C program, although different C programs may use different portions of the 2<sup>38</sup> bytes in memory.

Comment: Real-world example - the Motorola 68000 was a 32-bit architecture, but only exposed 24 address lines from the chip to the memory bus.  So while pointer types were 4 bytes wide, the upper 8 bits were not used for storing address values.  You could (and some people did) pack other data into those unused bits.  When the '020 came along, all 32 address lines were exposed to the memory bus.